# primefaces context menu do not update to dialog box input

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, contextmenu

I have see this problem.Please see my jsf page.

```
<h:form id="companyList">
            <p:contextMenu for="companiesDB" style="height:53px;">
                <p:menuitem value=" edit" update="panelGrid" icon="ui-icon-pencil" oncomplete="editCompany.show()" />

                <p:menuitem value=" delete" update="panelGrid" icon="ui-icon-closethick" onclick="editCompany.show()" />
            </p:contextMenu>

            <p:dataTable id="companiesDB" var="companies"
                value="#{companyController.companyList}" rowKey="#{companies.pkId}"
                selection="#{companyController.selectedCompany}"
                selectionMode="single" paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rows="20" >
                <p:column headerText="name">
                    #{companies.companyName}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="desc">
                    #{companies.description}
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog header="edit mode" widgetVar="editCompany"
                modal="true" height="160" width="390"
                id="dialog" resizable="false">

                <p:panelGrid cellpadding="10" id="panelGrid" >
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column width="300">
                            <h:outputText value="name:" style="float:left;" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText   value="#{companyController.selectedCompany.companyName}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="desc:" style="float:right;" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText  
                                value="#{companyController.selectedCompany.description}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                </p:panelGrid>

                <br />
                <br />
                <p:commandButton value="save" icon="ui-icon-check"
                    style="float:right; margin-right:25px;" update="companiesDB"
                    oncomplete="addCompany.hide();"
                    action="#{companyController.insertCompany()}">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:dialog>
 </h:form>
```

And console error was :
/company.xhtml @46,91 value="#{companyController.selectedCompany.companyName}": Target Unreachable, 'selectedCompany' returned null

Answer (score 1):

try renaming your dialog id to `mydialog` (just to be on a safe side)

and update your menu item entry as following (notice the `update="mydialog"`):

```
<p:menuitem value="edit" update="mydialog" icon="ui-icon-pencil" oncomplete="editCompany.show()" />
```

also , make sure the edit button will be enabled only after a selection in table was made... otherwise you will get the null pointer...

you can achieve it with something like

```
<p:menuitem value="edit" disabled=#{companyController.selectedCompany eq null}.....
```

and add two `p:ajax` in your table

```
<p:dataTable.......>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="contextMenuID" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="contextMenuID" />
```

last thing : add `id=contextMenuID` to your context menu

Comment: thank you for feedback.Where i need to write this contextID ? please explain contextID and how to use it ?

Comment: `<p:contextMenu id="contextMenuID" for="companiesDB" style="height:53px;">`

Comment: Daniel, disabled property of the p:menuitem ?  <p:menuitem value="View" update="mydialog" icon="ui-icon-search"
      oncomplete="editCompany.show()" disabled="#{companyController.selectedCompany eq null}"/>

Comment: My contextMenu is not rendered.clicked mouse2 that is not rendered.

Comment: When clicked mouse 2, the first time contextMenu is rendered, then it is not rendered during  about 1 seconds

Comment: ok, what about the original question (first 3 line of my answer... ) ? did it fixed the error you had in the original question ?

Comment: Why not rendered contextMenu?      <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form:contextMenuID"  />
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":form:contextMenuID" />

Comment: I did told you to render it , `update="contextMenuID"` should be anought

Comment: Also error is : javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with identifier "contextMenuID" referenced from "form:cars".

Comment: Sorry.javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with identifier "contextMenuID" referenced from "companyList:companiesDB".

Comment: try replacing the `update="contextMenuID"` with `update="@form"`

Comment: Okey. Good job.Thank u very much Mr.Daniel and for feedback to my question

Comment: You are welcome, you can try `update="companyList:contextMenuID"` instead of `update="@form"` , let me know if it works for you , if it does , leave it this way cause it will refresh the context menu only instead the whole form , Also accept my answer if it solved your question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hello, Daniel. i see one problem again which is the datatable row select value.First time i selected some datatable's row.Second time i selected one row this appear to me previous selected value. How do resolve ?

Comment: Did your original question was solved by my answer? If thats the case , then accept my answer and post new question.